# Is it possible to have complex orthogonal columns? How about complex orthonormal columns?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality, orthonormal, orthogonal-matrices

If such instances are possible than would the four fundamental subspaces still apply to these complex orthogonal or orthonormal matrices?

The Four Fundamental Subspaces
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4RaA.png)

Comment: Since real numbers are a subset of complex numbers, then real orthogonal columns are also complex orthogonal columns, are they not?

Comment: What about complex orthonormal columns? Do those exist?

Comment: Well, by the same token, real orthonormal columns are also complex orthonormal columns.

Comment: @Théophile Thanks I think I found a complex matrix that satisfies being orthonormal. would this matrix be considered orthonormal? Also if it is orthonormal than does that mean the inverse of this matrix is not the transpose of the matrix as with real number orthormal matrices? \begin{pmatrix}4i&-\sqrt{5}\\ \:\:\sqrt{5}&4i\end{pmatrix}

In other words is the matrix above orthonormal and does not fulfill this rule: A^TA=I

Comment: Are you thinking of unitary matrices?

Comment: @hinterland Note that for complex vectors, orthogonality and norm are typically defined using [a sesquilinear "dot-product"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Complex_vectors), so for your example the columns would be neither orthogonal nor of length $1$.